# Xcode 9.2 - Can't see "iOS Simulator" within run destination

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.2

I'm trying to run my application with a Xcode simulator but I can't select any simulator since my only options are the one showed in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGPmN.png)

As per [apple guide](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev2809b6cff), I should see the section "iOS Simulator" below "Build Only Device", but within my Xcode that section is missing.

What I've already tried to solve the issue:

- Set iOS Deployment Target under Project > Info > Deployment Target and restart Xcode.
- Check if there are simulators installed within Xcode>Preferences>Components. There are Simulator 11.0 and 11.1
- Check if there are simulator within Window > Device and Simulator > Simulators. There are around 30 simulators.
- Restart Xcode
- Reinstall Xcode

I am using Xcode 9.2 and macOS version 10.12.6.

Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Try creating a new iOS project and see if the simulators show up there. Also make sure you have the right target selected next to the run destination popup. (If your project has a framework or something in it that is selected the simulators may not show)

Comment: Yes, I can see "iOS Simulator" section within a new iOS project. If it may help, my project is build from Unity3D. Regarding the target, I just see my application next to the run destination popup.

Comment: Unity isn't always the best at properly setting up projects for Xcode. First thing I would do is click on the warnings tab in Xcode (it's the little exclamation mark in a triangle on top of the left part of the window). Odds are the first warning is about updating to recommended project settings, click it and then click perform changes in the sheet that drops down. If that doesn't solve it you may have to compare the build settings of the Unity project and the fresh one you made and guess at adjustments. (At least Xcode lets you open more than one project at a time…)

Comment: I've found the solution. I needed to change Build Settings > Supported Platform from "iphoneos" to "iOS". Thank you for the help!

Comment: The last solution works for me!